# My translator does not output what i want it to

Tags: python, ascii, emoji

I need my code to output 'hey ' when the input written is 'hey :)'. Instead it outputs 'h'

```
def emojiChanger(word):
    emoji = " "
    for letter in word:
        if letter in ":)":
            emoji = emoji + ""
        elif letter in ":(":
            emoji = emoji + "☹️"
        else:
            emoji = emoji + letter
        return emoji

print(emojiChanger(input('How are you doing? ')))
```

output:

```
How are you doing? :)
```

alternative output: # What I need to fix

```
How are you doing? hey :)
 h
```

I need it to output: hey

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your question? There are multiple problems with your code, like to start, `return` is indented too deep. For tips, see [ask]. You can [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can only go into one of the `if` or `elif` or `else` branches (and it can never go into `elif` for `:` because the `if` already captures that). You need to add stuff to the output string in all of these cases, probably outside the conditional.

However, you are examining one letter at a time, so `:` followed by *anything* will add  and `)` anywhere else in the line will do that too; and `(` anywhere will trigger ☹️

A better approach altogether is perhaps

```
def emojiChanger(word):
    return word.replace(':)', '').replace(':(', '☹️')
```

Answer (score -1):

you always enter the first `if`.  use

```
def emojiChanger(word):
    return  "hey " if ":)" in word else None
```

you can also define unique return values when `:(` shows up

```
def emojiChanger(word):
    return "hey " if ":)" in word else "not hey ☹️" if ":(" in word else None
```